# Bootstrap tour not working in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap tour functionality in my MVC application. To implement the tour I have done everything mentioned in the following bootstrap link

But still tour does not run for my application.

I am already using boostrap so I am using following files

> If you are using Bootstrap, include bootstrap-tour.min.css and bootstrap-tour.min.js:

and then the required Javascript code in index file on  $(document).ready(function () {

```
// Instance the tour
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#my-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
  {
    element: "#my-other-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  }
]});

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();

// Start the tour
tour.start();
```

If anyone of you have any clue what's going wrong here.

Comment: Also, I get the reference Error: Page not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap tour in MVC5. I'm sure you have everything in place.
Please check the following places:

1. The tour css and js are referred after bootstrap, as well as jquery;
2. Make sure #my-element does exist, by `alert($("#my-element").html());` etc.
3. Something like tr cannot be an element.
4. Use `tour.restart()` instead of `start()`. Because you might encountered my problem here: [Bootstrap tour needs to clear cache to work again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468409/bootstrap-tour-needs-to-clear-cache-to-work-again)